# Convert Blob file to an ArcObjects object

Tags: arcobjects, c#, arcgis-engine

I have a blob file which I take from a database. This blob is actually an MXD file. I want to load this MXD to an `axLayoutControl` (ArcGIS Engine). But for security reasons I do not want to write this on disk and then load it with `LoadMXD(string path)` method. I want to pass it to my layout control directly. So I need to convert it to some interface like `IMXDContents`. Below is the code I use. But the exception "Class not registered (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG))" is thrown on `ObjectStream.LoadObject(ref guid, k)` . I googled this and the only thing I found was that I should change my platform target to x86 instead of Any CPU. Believe me I tried this in every posible way. And still not working. Can anyone please help?

```
IXMLStream pXMLStream = new XMLStreamClass();
pXMLStream.LoadFromBytes(ref bytes); //bytes is the cast of blob file to bytes array

IObjectStream ObjectStream = new ObjectStreamClass();
ObjectStream.Stream = pXMLStream as IStream;

IMxdContents k = new PageLayoutClass();
Guid guid = typeof(IMxdContents).GUID;

ObjectStream.LoadObject(ref guid, k);
```

Comment: Either it's a BLOB *or* a file, it can't be both at the same time.  This is the heart of your issue, since the map document readers are all file-based.  If you really want to implement this questionable "security" algorithm, you'll need to capture the information represented in the MXD, store *that* in the BLOB, and reinvent the entire map document in your application.

Comment: This is basically what ArcFM stored displays are/do.
Did you try:
var mxd = ObjectStream.LoadObject(ref guid, null) as IMxdContents;
// then get the map from the mxd and load into the ArcEngine page layout control

Comment: Thank you. You're right. That's not the right way to do. I took     IPageLayout and saved it to database. Now I can retrieve it properly. @Vince